# Counting bijections

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let there be a given set $|S|=10$. What is the probability that, if we choose a random mapping $f:S \to S$ that $f$ will be bijective if:

a) We know that there are two elements which have a different picture (i.e. we have $(x_1,x_2) \in S^2, f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$)?

b) We know that there are two elements which give different pictures from the rest of the elements (i.e. there are $(x_1,x_2) \in S^2, f(x_i)= f(x) \implies x_i=x, i \in \{1,2 \} $)?

My solution would be: Let $A= S_{10}$ the symmetric group, $B_a= \{ \text{mappings with  } f(x_1), f(x_2) \text{  different from each other}\}, \\ B_b=\{ \text{mappings with } f(x_1), f(x_2) \text{ fixed such that } f(x_i)= f(x) \implies x_i=x, i \in \{1,2 \}  \}$.

a) Would be formulated as follows
$\mathbb{P}(A|B_a) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B_a)}{\mathbb{P}(B_a)}= \frac{ \mathbb{P}(A)}{P(B_a)}= \frac{ \frac{10!}{10^{10}}}{1- \mathbb{P}(B_a^c)}=\frac{ \frac{10!}{10^{10}}}{1-\frac{1}{10}}$ if my reasoning is correct.

b) $\mathbb{P}(A|B_b) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B_b)}{\mathbb{P}(B_b)}= \frac{ \mathbb{P}(A)}{P(B_b)}= \frac{ \frac{10!}{10^{10}}}{2\binom{10}{2} \frac{1}{10^2}}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I would do a) as follows: There are $10^{10}$ functions from $S$ to $S$ overall. $10$ of those do not fulfil the conditions of a) (the constant functions), so there are $10^{10} - 10$ functions that are possible. $10!$ of those are actually bijections, so we have $$\frac{10!}{10^{10} - 10} \approx 0.00036288$$ where the $-10$ have an effect five decimal places later (it's $0.0003628800004$ instead of $0.00036288$ exactly).